# Unreal build using UnrealBuildTool with the command line

Tags: macos, command-line, unreal-engine4

Yesterday things were running fine. Today? Not so much

In Unreal on a Mac using blueprints only, I get the error:

> LogPlayLevel: Error: ERROR: Stage Failed. Missing receipt Check that this target has been built.
> LogPlayLevel: AutomationTool exiting with ExitCode=103 (Error_MissingExecutable)
>
> LogPlayLevel: Completed Launch On Stage: Build Task, Time: 1.776950
>
> LogPlayLevel: Completed Launch On Stage: Deploy Task, Time: 0.000039
>
> LogPlayLevel: Error: RunUAT ERROR: AutomationTool was unable to run successfully.
>
> PackagingResults: Error: Launch failed! Missing UE4Game binary.
>
> You may have to build the UE4 project with your IDE. Alternatively, build using UnrealBuildTool with the commandline:
>
> UE4Game [Platform] [Configuration]

So I try to build from command line:

```
cd "/Users/Shared/Epic Games/UE_4.23/Engine/Binaries/Mac"
open UE4Editor.app --args "/Users/me/Documents/Unreal Projects/Some Folder/MyProject.uproject" -run=cook -targetplatform=Android
```

This switches focus from the Terminal to UREditor but nothing happens. What am I missing / got wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Note to future self:

I was able to get around the hold-up above, by simply creating a packaged Android build - which built beautifully and successfully.

That said I'd still like to know the command line to build an Android version.